# Composer install cannot resolve dependencies for ZF2 project anymore

Tags: zend-framework, zend-framework2, composer-php, zend-framework3

Since Zend has been constantly publishing ZF3 versions of its core packages, I have problems getting my old ZF2 application to work.

If I run `composer install` with a valid composer.lock in place I get the follwing warnings with most ZF dependencies:

```
- Installing zendframework/zend-stdlib (2.7.7)
  Downloading: 100%         
  Failed to download zendframework/zend-stdlib from dist: The checksum verification of the file failed (downloaded from https://packages.zendframework.com/composer/zendframework-zend-stdlib-2.7.7-19d9a4.zip)
  Now trying to download from source
- Installing zendframework/zend-stdlib (2.7.7)
  Cloning baa65aec7bc75260254b5f03447f0c16360f9e59
```

Since I’ve got a lot of dependencies like that, install/cloning takes forever and never finishes, cause my VM runs out of memory.

Now I tried to either run `composer update` or delete composer.lock and run `composer install` again. I even tried removing the packages.zendframework.com repo from composer.json, since Zend says, its not needed anymore.

However, due to the new ZF3 version, I get unresolvable requirements.

Example:

```
Loading composer repositories with package information
Updating dependencies (including require-dev)
Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages.

  Problem 1
    - jhuet/zdt-logger-module dev-master requires zendframework/zend-developer-tools ^1.1.0 -> satisfiable by zendframework/zend-developer-tools[1.2.x-dev, 1.1.x-dev].
    - Can only install one of: zendframework/zend-developer-tools[dev-master, 1.2.x-dev].
    - Conclusion: don't install zendframework/zend-servicemanager 2.7.7
    - Conclusion: don't install zendframework/zend-servicemanager 3.1.1
    - Conclusion: don't install zendframework/zend-servicemanager 3.1.0
    - Installation request for zendframework/zend-developer-tools dev-master -> satisfiable by zendframework/zend-developer-tools[dev-master].
    - Conclusion: don't install zendframework/zend-servicemanager 2.7.6|install zendframework/zend-servicemanager 3.1.0
    - Installation request for zfcampus/zf-apigility-admin ~1.0 -> satisfiable by zfcampus/zf-apigility-admin[1.0.0, 1.0.1, 1.0.2, 1.0.3, 1.0.4, 1.0.5, 1.1.0, 1.1.1, 1.1.2, 1.2.0, 1.2.1, 1.2.2, 1.3.0, 1.3.1, 1.3.2, 1.3.3, 1.4.0, 1.4.1, 1.4.2, 1.4.3, 1.5.0, 1.5.1, 1.5.2, 1.5.3, 1.5.4, 1.5.5, 1.5.6, 1.5.7].
    - Installation request for jhuet/zdt-logger-module dev-master -> satisfiable by jhuet/zdt-logger-module[dev-master].
    - Installation request for zf-commons/zfc-rbac ~2.0 -> satisfiable by zf-commons/zfc-rbac[2.0.0, 2.1.0, 2.1.1, 2.1.2, 2.2.0, 2.3.0, 2.3.1, 2.4.0, 2.4.1, 2.4.2, v2.5.0, v2.5.1, v2.5.2, v2.5.3, v2.5.4, v2.5.5, v2.5.6].
    - jhuet/zdt-logger-module dev-master requires zendframework/zend-servicemanager 3.* -> satisfiable by zendframework/zend-servicemanager[3.0.0, 3.0.1, 3.0.2, 3.0.3, 3.1.0, 3.1.1].
    - Can only install one of: zendframework/zend-servicemanager[3.0.0, 2.7.5].
    - Can only install one of: zendframework/zend-servicemanager[3.0.1, 2.7.5].
    - Can only install one of: zendframework/zend-servicemanager[3.0.2, 2.7.5].
    - zendframework/zend-developer-tools 1.1.x-dev requires zendframework/zend-servicemanager ^2.7.5 || ^3.0.3 -> satisfiable by zendframework/zend-servicemanager[2.7.5, 2.7.6, 2.7.7, 3.0.3, 3.1.0, 3.1.1].
    - Conclusion: don't install zendframework/zend-servicemanager 3.0.3
```

The consequences: I’m not able to get my ZF2 app into working condition anymore. How can I fix this?

This is my composer.json:

```
{
    "name": "myapp",
    "description": "My app",
    "version": "1.5.0",
    "require": {
        "php": "~7.0",
        "ext-intl": ">=1.1.0",
        "ext-mbstring": "*",
        "zendframework/zendframework": "~2.5",
        "zf-commons/zfc-user": "~1.0",
        "zf-commons/zfc-rbac": "~2.0",
        "zendframework/zendoauth": "~2.0",
        "zfcampus/zf-apigility": "~1.0",
        "zfcampus/zf-development-mode": "~2.0",
        "aws/aws-sdk-php-zf2": "~2.0",
        "goalio/goalio-forgotpassword": "~1.0",
        "maglnet/magl-markdown": "~1.4",
        "ocramius/proxy-manager": "~1.0"
    },
    "require-dev": {
        "zfcampus/zf-apigility-admin": "~1.0",
        "zfcampus/zf-apigility-documentation": "~1.0",
        "zendframework/zend-developer-tools": "dev-master",
        "jhuet/zdt-logger-module": "dev-master",
        "bjyoungblood/bjy-profiler": "dev-master"
    }
}
```

I hope, this is solvable somehow without a lot of manual work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

These are issues you may always run into when you require something like dev-master. The best practice would be to stick to semantic version numbers and if a package maintainer follows the semantic versioning you shouldn't run into requiring packages with breaking changes.

In your case you rely on a dev-master version of "jhuet/zdt-logger-module". This one is recently updated to support ZF3. If you remove `"jhuet/zdt-logger-module": "dev-master",`, it seems to work for me.

To keep that package you need this: `"jhuet/zdt-logger-module": "^0.3"`. This makes sure it doesn't load the newer 1.0.0 package that requires ZF3.